# Implementation of Association Rules in Javascript

Tags: efficiency, javascript

I have implemented an interactive visualization with d3.js, javascript to explore the frequency and various combinations of co-occurring item sets. I want to complement the interactive exploration with some automated options.

Does someone know an efficient javascript implementation of the association rules mining ?

My typical scenario will have just up to 30 different items.
There are some good web site with implementations of frequent item set mining (improvements from the initial apriori algorithm): http://www.borgelt.net/apriori.html

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how efficient they are, but I did find some implementations:

- https://github.com/dmarges/apriori
- https://github.com/seratch/apriori.js